# Calling numDeriv:hessian() with multiple-parameter-objective-function in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, statistics, linear-algebra, rcpp

My aim is to call the `hessian()` function from the `numDeriv` `R` package from a cpp file (using `Rcpp`).

A toy example:
I want to calculate a hessian of a one-dimensional function x^n at the point x=1 with parameter n=3.
R code:

```
H = call_1D_hessian_in_C(K=1)
print(H)
```

Cpp code:

```
double one_dimensional(double X, double N){
  return pow(X,N);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double call_1D_hessian_in_C(double K) {

  Rcpp::Environment numDeriv("package:numDeriv");
  Rcpp::Function hessian = numDeriv["hessian"];
  double param = 3;

  Rcpp::List hessian_results =
  hessian(
    Rcpp::_["func"] = Rcpp::InternalFunction(one_dimensional), 
    Rcpp::_["x"] = 1.0,
    Rcpp::_["N"] = param
  );

  return hessian_results[0];

}
```

This works fine and I indeed get "6" at the output.
However my true goal is to calculate hessians of K-dimensional functions, therefore K=/=1. I try the following:

```
H = call_KD_hessian_in_C(K=2)
print(H)
```

And in Cpp:

```
NumericVector k_dimensional(NumericVector X, double N){
  return pow(X,N);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double call_KD_hessian_in_C(double K) {

  Rcpp::Environment numDeriv("package:numDeriv");
  Rcpp::Function hessian = numDeriv["hessian"];
  double param = 3;

  Rcpp::NumericVector x = rep(1.0,K);

  Rcpp::List hessian_results = 
  hessian(
    Rcpp::_["func"] = Rcpp::InternalFunction(k_dimensional),
    Rcpp::_["x"] = x,
    Rcpp::_["N"] = param
  );

  return hessian_results[0];

}
```

But now I get "invalid pointer" errors. A am not sure how to provide the hessian function call with a cpp function that takes a set of parameters to evaluate the partial derivatives at...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of quick notes:

- Try the implementation in *R* and then move it to *C++*.

  - Provides a reference point and makes sure that everything works as intended.
- Search paths and names matter

  - Explicitly load `numDeriv` package before compiling.
  - Respect capitalization `X` vs. `x`.
- Ensure output types are accurate

  - From  [`?numDeriv::hessian`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numDeriv/numDeriv.pdf#page=8), the output type is an **N** x **N** `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` instead of `Rcpp::List`.

#### Implementing in R

Coding the example and running it in **pure** *R* would give:

```
k = 2
k_dimensional = function(x, N) {
 x ^ N 
}

numDeriv::hessian(k_dimensional, x = rep(1, k), N = 3)
```

> Error in hessian.default(k_dimensional, x = rep(1, k), N = 3) :
>
> Richardson method for hessian assumes a scalar valued function.

So, immediately, this means that the `k_dimensional()` function is missing a reduction down to a scalar (e.g. single value).

#### Environment Run Time Error with C++ variant

After compiling the original code, there is a **runtime error** or when the function was called the issue an issue appears. For example, we have:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("path/to/call_KD_hessian_in_C.cpp")
call_KD_hessian_in_C(K = 2)
```

This provides the error of:

> Error in call_KD_hessian_in_C(2) :
>
> Cannot convert object to an environment: [type=character; target=ENVSXP].

As we are using an *R* function found in a package not loaded by default, we must explicitly load it via `library()` or `require()` before calling the function.

Therefore, the process to avoid an environment issue should be:

```
# Compile the routine
Rcpp::sourceCpp("path/to/call_KD_hessian_in_C.cpp")

# Load numDeriv to ensure it is on the search path
library("numDeriv")

# Call function
call_KD_hessian_in_C(2)
```

#### Cleaned Up C++ Implementation

From prior discussion, note that we've:

1. Changed the function used with the hessian to be a **scalar** or **single value**, e.g. `double`, instead of a **vector of values**, e.g. `NumericVector`.
2. Ensured that before the function call the `numDeriv` *R* package is loaded.
3. Changed the return type expected from the `hessian()` function from `Rcpp::List` to `Rcpp::NumericMatrix`.

This results in the following *C++* code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

double k_dimensional_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double N){
// ^^ Change return type from NumericVector to double

  // Speed up the process by writing the _C++_ loop
  // instead of relying on Rcpp sugar.
  double total = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < x.size(); ++i) {
      total += std::pow(x[i], N);
  }

  // Return the accumulated total
  return total;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix call_KD_hessian_in_C(double K) {

  // Ensure that numDeriv package is loaded prior to calling this function
  Rcpp::Environment numDeriv("package:numDeriv");
  Rcpp::Function hessian = numDeriv["hessian"];

  double param = 3;
  Rcpp::NumericVector x = Rcpp::rep(1.0, K);

  // Switched from Rcpp::List to Rcpp::NumericMatrix
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix hessian_results = 
  hessian(
    Rcpp::_["func"] = Rcpp::InternalFunction(k_dimensional_cpp),
    Rcpp::_["x"] = x,    // use lower case x to match function signature.
    Rcpp::_["N"] = param
  );

  // Return the calculated hessian
  return hessian_results;
}
```

Testing the routine gives:

```
# Ensure numDeriv is on search path
library("numDeriv")

# Call function
call_KD_hessian_in_C(K = 2)
#              [,1]         [,2]
# [1,] 6.000000e+00 3.162714e-12
# [2,] 3.162714e-12 6.000000e+00
```